# How to get the first N rows where the sum is ≥ X?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:

- Products(ID, weight, expired, ...)

I would like to get the N first products which expired is false and sum of the weight is form `example >= 5kg`.

How could I do this query?

Thanks so much.

EDIT: it seems that I was not very clear in my question. For example I can have this products:

- p1: ID = 1, weight = 1;
- p2: ID = 2, weight = 1;
- p3: ID = 3, weight = 1;
- p4: ID = 4, weight = 2;

For example, I would like to get the first N products which sum of weights is 3. The order is the same.

So I would like to get for example p1, p2 and p3 because the sum of weights is 3 (in this case N is 3 because I need 3 products), so it is correct. I could get p1 and p4 and it would be correct (int this case N is 2 because I need only two products), or p2 and p4... and so on.

Comment: select top N ... where ... order by...?

Comment: What means `SUM of the weight` in this context? What do you want to sum? How could a single record be summed?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve here. Can you, at the very least, show us example input and desired output? Showing us the basis for the query that you already have would probably also be useful.

Comment: It sounds to me like the  question is getting the x first not expried products, but x as to be limited so that sum(weigth) is limited to 5 kg. But still, I could interpret wrong.

Comment: Which SQL Server version? Should be easy with a running sum

Comment: You want all the possible combinations or any single combination of weights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write as:

```
select top 10 * from -- top N goes here
 (
 SELECT *,SUM(weight) OVER (partition BY expired ORDER BY Id asc) as cumulativesum
 FROM 
 Products
 WHERE expired = 0
  )T 
  where cumulativesum>=5
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5fb4/2)</kbd>

Comment: thank so much for the demo, bit I have a doubt. The first result says: ID =3 and cumulative = 5. If the row with ID = 3 has a weight of 4, how is it possible that the cumulative sum is 5?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.*
FROM Prodcts p
WHERE p.expired = 0
AND   p.weight >= 5
```

However, currently it's not clear how you want to `sum` a single record.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter data by column/expression you need to use `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE column = 0 -- or column = 'false'
```

In order to filter data by aggregate expression, you need to use `HAVING` clause. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE column = 0 -- or column = 'false'
HAVING SUM(something) > 100
```

In order to get `TOP` records of something you should use appropriate `ORDER BY` clause either - you need to sort the data in such way that the `TOP N` will always give you the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sum the weight which is what your question implies try something like

```
Select ID, [Weight]
From
(select ID, SUM([weight]) as [weight], Row_number() over(order by ID) as N
Where Expired = 0
Having SUM(weight) > = 5) X
where N <= @x
```

Or if you want heaviest first

```
Select ID, [Weight]
From
(select ID, SUM([weight]) as [weight], Row_number() over(order by SUM([weight]) desc) as N
Where Expired = 0
Having SUM(weight) > = 5) X
where N <= @x
```

Where @X is the number required